# Encryption in URL

Tags: php, encryption

I have an URL.
My URL type: "http://myweb.com/id=W5OAGejZ1HpuHri7BB1c%2BXHSYs2c47eyJFhpmroalPXZ5SUIgeUbqu7hJUVFVwPOA0xRI3ILJVHQ5QgBwtWpE1x0%2Fq10VVrmduMU5PiYguW1cXog4azzDvjcbb3%2BVpMDKe5QmvjLgJ9M4TXosTYR%2FOVzIPvXD%2BjeTEFtIM2g6siUcPBOeK5ubQh1QYB%2FCSbgnFsh2mpx3r%2FXBXI09I4q%2Be7hDSITcyIeYzFf1LoovBKotYcYSxhrZkbtIz2utl8PbpGa5G49EAwcKyossEo21dumTfkfJFoXUfmhH7amGcqbKUBOvtmhRwaMqrqoR6Vjd%2FKBCLrszpCRXX%2FdY6Kg0A7AUUNWdedizKCiDYdYL1IMUZ12od7HZNuHCruWPe43uhoxhjyhzx9oFl4rf6f8aM58b6KDtgiBbDwZNiICltUHq6htdzq2KwPRz8tl0WvZaaV3UC7vkfzfH%2FsRrv%2BB8MlsPrW6YfDOwupf0ax%2BJjc8oy%2BD%2BXv53swU5%2BS0dKQv94sgPNoQKG05oi4%2BO7M4gcw5Otp7O6qDFv5yhYnywJD8F6CXWUmHU9WoFRGoQnwdDwoMySYsiM4jCT9aq4s08%2Bx2m8EngPHr36aN7xJbc1yVgJUJjmCea5xCl4Hp6X3h%2BJMvUm25jbzi9ZXOFHHsp2lboLgXY1cM0b%2F1azWMaEgWLEXXbhIL36fC%2FQCQTk%2FvNnFZJLeye2LVbxBWVpyKxvC9ire1lxm0OrugnhhJle0lDFpl5O1cJwwORx2eUqwdmAJvWqh6SxBPyoxISKoIO6t4gRN%2BWMCHrwylBTsLvVKqwHdv2ulv88a3HHpOvTWuDlUb%2B0ADjnhAZ2jnVadSgX3r%2FQTaWVswD4rfRTPqdzmmHmIdC%2B%2BmOiUuMRL9qDXei4kxfeyODgkVJ4P9yEplsB2HfVM9cHU1ks4oq8bXIRb9j%2FqE%2FRsEFuQs%2FfQvBZXjEQK%2FnUiIHJ%2BZQcVTEPgsBPcewNjH85vc61WKd%2B3R6mbFuY4%2BJUdIt%2BaUjRohUP8P7R4Bh5WWA%2F%2B2odAn1fT5Xkn07XCWmoE5MBBTyFRXQBU6HImYDJ2Gk95xVn65jGrs5XbsKUjYEis1MQe4N59RjA%3D%3D"

I want to need decode the line behind the id "W5OAGejZ1HpuHri7BB.....9RjA%3D%3D". I think it encryption base 64. But when I decode it, it not true. If you know about it, please tell me more info it. Thank you..

Comment: Maybe the owner didn't want users to decrypt his encrypted text.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, since ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. We're not here to play the [guessing game](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/), but you can guess yourself: [determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/3989/45523)

Comment: Sorry. I'm newbie.I am don't know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text looks like URL encoded Base64. First separate the data, de-URL encode (specifically the %2B, %2F and %3d hex characters to respectively +, / and =. Then base64 decode the string.

Then you will have a sequence of data bytes, probably not a text string. That may be what you want or it may be encrypted, in the latter case you would need the encryption key to decrypt the data.